# Using column values as column names in dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'animal': 'dog', 'years':10}, 
                   {'animal': 'dog', 'years':5},
                   {'animal': 'cat', 'years':3},
                   {'animal': 'cat', 'years':7}])
```

giving me:

```
  animal  years
0    dog     10
1    dog      5
2    cat      3
3    cat      7
```

Given the number of cats and dogs is always the same, how can I can turn it into:

```
       dog   cat
years  10     3
        5     7
```

My ultimate goal is to make a boxplot showing years distrubution across each animal type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: @villoro Unfortunately not. It lists pivot methods in pandas that seem to require aggregation of results. I do not need aggregation. jezrael's answer answers my question perfectly and leads straight to the point without going into lengthy explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter per `animal` and reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index([df.groupby('animal').cumcount(), 'animal'])['years']
         .unstack()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df1)
   cat  dog
0    3   10
1    7    5
```